# Plot model's testing accuracy when loading a model using load_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, plot, keras

I'm trying to plot a testing accuracy for a model that is called using `tf.keras.models.load_model` (I'd initially saved the model as a .h5 file after getting satisfactory results in training & validation accuracies).

During training & validation, I used the following codes to plot training & validation accuracies:

```
epoch_list2 = list(range(1, len(hist2.history['acc']) + 1))
plt.plot(epoch_list2, hist2.history['acc'], epoch_list2, hist2.history['val_acc'])
plt.legend(("Training Accuracy", "Validation Accuracy"))
plt.show()
```

However, when I now the call the model to test it on unseen data (for demo purposes), I'm using the following codes to first load the model, then evaluate on the test data & finally calculate the accuracy:

```
# Load the model
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('/home/ubuntu/CNN_Model.h5')
print(model.summary())

# Use model.evaluate:
test_score = model.evaluate(testset, labels, verbose = 0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (test_score[1]*100))
```

How do I now plot the testing accuracy score & is it possible to plot all three (i.e. training, validation & testing scores) in the same graph **when loading a model**?

Thanks in advance!

Abhay.

**EDIT**

So after searching stack, i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004071/how-can-we-plot-accuracy-and-loss-graphs-from-a-keras-model-saved-earlier) that helps first save the *training history* and load it back. With that sorted out, how do I now plot the training, validation & test scores in a single plot?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? It seems like you were able to load the data and you already provided some code that plots the data during training. Does that not work? Or how does the result differ from your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you could do is to save the history.history['val_acc'], history.history['train_acc'] into a separate .csv file. And after you load the model and get an accuracy on the test data, you plot them together in a plot where test_accuracy, of course, is just a dot on plot, make sure to use "maker" in plot.